# python: adding key value to dictionary with variable name as key

Tags: python, dictionary

Having:

```
foo=1
bar=2
baz=3
```

what is the fastest way to come to:

```
mydict = {'foo':1,'bar':2, 'baz':3}
```

Or in other words, having

```
mylist=[foo,bar,baz]
```

how do I change that into a dict

Comment: If you only have `mylist` to work from, you can't, at any speed.

Comment: Grab all local variables from `locals()`: `{k:v for (k,v) in locals().items() if not k.startswith('_')}`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen: And hope there aren't any other local variables...

Comment: OP very clearly stated he just has 3 - if that's a lie then that's an OP-problem ;)

Answer (score 0):

Having:

```
foo=1
bar=2
baz=3
```

you could use:

```
mydict = {'foo':foo, 'bar':bar, 'baz':baz}
```

But if you only have

```
mylist=[foo,bar,baz]
```

you can't change it into a `dict`, unless the values are in a specific order, in which case you could use

```
mydict = {'foo'mylist[0], 'bar':mylist[1], 'baz':mylist[2]}
```